# Backing up to Box.net account (webdav and Deja)

Tags: backup, deja-dup

I have a Box.net account and it's feeling neglected so I decided to place my backups there since it's bigger than my Ubuntu One storage.

When I try to set this up I get an error though.

I set it up like this:

- Backup location: WebDAV
- Server: www.box.com/dav
- Use https (yes)
- Port 443
- Folder: /Deja/ Username: [email address]

These are the same details used to add my box account as a server in nautilus (which worked) but this says "HTTP Error: Cannot resolve hostname (www.box.com/dav)" when I try to run a backup.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

James

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out!

Under your storage tab...
Backup Location - WebDAV
Server - www.box.com
Check the HTTPS box
Port - 443
Folder - /dav/optionalsubdirectory
Username - optional

Comment: Created an account just to comment that this worked for me. Nice job!

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround you can use [davfs2](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/davfs2):

`sudo apt-get install davfs2`

Create a folder where you would like to mount the box.net "drive":

`sudo mkdir /media/box.net`

Test-mount box.net WebDAV

`sudo mount -t davfs https://www.box.net/dav /media/box.net`

Make it permanent:

```
sudo su
echo “https://www.box.net/dav username password” >> /etc/davfs2/secrets`
```

(username and password of course being your username/email-address and password respectively)
NB: Yes, this is your password in plain text but it's visible only to sudoers.

Mount it on every start:

```
sudo su
gedit /etc/davfs2/davfs2.conf
```

change the `dav_group davfs2` line to `dav_group users`

`sudo gedit /etc/fstab`

and insert

`http://www.box.net/dav /media/box.net davfs rw,user,noauto 0 0`

at the end. `noauto` is important. Otherwise the boot will hang.

Note that there are several other ways of accomplishing this, for example adding your user to the davfs2 group, having a secrets file just for the user in `~/.davfs2/secrets` etc. but this one should work.

All in all I've found the box.net WebDAV support to be flaky at times.

Comment: Awesome! I just got that set up and will now create a backup. Cheers!

Comment: Probably off-topic but after setting this up (I wasn't actually able to use it as a backup location, there was an error regarding no permissions to create a directory) I restarted my computer and now it won't get past the splash screen.
It doesn't freeze, it just sits there with dots going across. I tried booting recovery mode and the first thing it asks is for my username and password to my box account and then does nothing, hence my thinking it was related.

Comment: Do you have `noauto` removed? This sounds serious.

Comment: ....i do.....
would it help to boot to a liveusb, edit that file and reboot?
I'm not home right now but i can try when i get home.

Comment: Yes, removing the line from fstab will stop the wait. Try removing `noauto` first, this should be enough. If this doesn't work comment out the whole line.

Comment: Awesome, putting `noauto` back in has fixed the issue and the computer has booted, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As server you can't add URLs like in a browser. You just have to edit Server to "www.box.com" without /dav.

**Sorry for the wrong answer. Here the answer**
This is a bug in DejaDup and was submitted here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/deja-dup/+bug/975308
You can follow this bug to receive updates and it seems not to work at the moment.

Comment: Just tried changing www.box.com/dav to just www.box.com and I get "Not a WebDAV-enabled share"

Comment: I just updated my answer above ;)

Answer (score 0):

instead of "noauto" try "_netdev"

_netdev
  The filesystem resides on a device that requires network access (used to prevent the system from attempting to mount these filesystems until the network has been enabled on the system).